# Querying 2 Tables in a single query

Tags: php, sql, mysql, join

I have a table for posts and a table for categories, what i want is to select posts that are in a specific category. The problem is that the category is stored in another table and not in the posts table, here is the example:

### posts

```
id   title       body
---------------------------
125  Some title  Blah blah
```

### categories

```
postid  category
----------------
125     politic
```

I want in single query to fetch posts in the politic category by example, what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.title, 
       p.body
  FROM POSTS p
  JOIN CATEGORIES c ON c.postid = p.id
 WHERE c.category = 'politic'
```

The issue I have with your CATEGORIES table is that storing the category value as a string means the data isn't normalized - you should instead have a CATEGORY table:

### CATEGORY

- category_id (primary key, auto_increment)
- category_description

...and use the `category_id` value in the `CATEGORIES` table:

### CATEGORIES

- category_id (primary key, foreign key to CATEGORY.category_id)
- post_id (primary key, foreign key to POSTS.postid)

Comment: good point.   besides allowing many-to-many relationships and better form in general, categories having an associated post is kind of backwards.

Comment: Also, it is not clear from the sample data, but it does actually seem possible that a post has only one category (1 to 1) [from his wording of 'the category']. If that is the case, then the category id should be in the post table. Perhaps maybe I'm reading too much into it.

Comment: Storing the category name as a string does not mean the data isn't normalized. An integer identifier is not "more normalized" than a string identifier. Unless there are more attributes of categories than just their name, you have actually introduced a completely unnecessary table.

Comment: I guess the possibility of storing "politic", "POLitic", "POLOTIC", etc vs an INT value are lost on some...

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.* 
from posts p 
inner join categories c 
       on p.id = c.postid 
where 
     c.category = 'politic'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables in your query

```
SELECT *
FROM posts P
INNER JOIN categories C on C.post_id = P.id
WHERE C.category = 'politic'
```

You can intuitively (this is NOT exactly a technically correct explanation) think of this join as appending the category field to a row in posts with the shared id (this is the 'on C.post_id = P.id').  The WHERE clause indicates that you want only those rows where category is 'politic'.

Inner join is one of several join types.  Left join in particularly is another common one, and its difference in this situation is that rows of post without a match in categories would still be listed, but with nulls for the fields from categories.  (With inner join such rows would not remain)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29