# How to query 3 tables in a single query?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, join

I'm really sorry for the first post as i didn't explain everything.

Basically i have 3 tables, One for posts, One for Categories, & Another to link categories with posts.

I want in a single MySQL query to select posts that are under a specific category.

```
posts(id,title,body)
---------------------
125,Some title,Blah blah


categories(id,name)
---------------------
1,politic
2,entertainment

linker(categoryid,postid)
---------------------
2,125
```

I want in single query to fetch posts in the entertainment category by example, what to do?

Thanks

Comment: Didn't you just ask this with 2 tables? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175544/querying-2-tables-in-a-single-query

Comment: "I'm really sorry for the first post as i didn't explain everything."

Comment: Did you make a mistake?  What's going on with the trig functions in that last code block's query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
     p.*
from 
     posts p
     inner join linker l on l.postid = p.id
     inner join categories c on c.categoryid = l.categoryid
where 
     c.name = 'entertainment'
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer, what if 2 categories are assigned to one post?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same exact thing, you just have to join 3 tables intead of 2 :

```
SELECT P.id post_id,
       P.title,
       P.body,
       C.id category_id,
       C.name
FROM posts P
INNER JOIN linker L
    ON P.id = L.postid
INNER JOIN categories C
    ON L.categoryid = C.id
WHERE C.name = 'Category'
```

Don't be afraid to do your own tests. If you understand how to join two tables, you should understand how to join three, four and more.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer, what if 2 categories are assigned to one post?

Comment: Then you would have two different rows with the same post_id but two different category_id. Best way to know is to try!

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL statement should provide you with a basis for what you are trying to do.

```
select p.*
from posts p
inner join linker l
on l.postid = p.id
inner join categories c
on l.categoryid = c.id
where c.name = 'entertainment'
```

Answer (score 0):

If a post belongs to 2 categories, you can still use pinkfloydx33's query with DISTINCT in the select statement:

```
select 
     DISTINCT p.*
from 
     posts p
     inner join linker l on l.postid = p.id
     inner join categories c on c.categoryid = l.categoryid
where 
     c.name = 'entertainment'
```

The result set will show only one record.

Comment: What? Absolutely not! DISTINCT remove duplicate tuples, that's it, that's all. If the tuples are (1,1) and (1,2), there's no reason to remove one of them, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: David wanted a single query that results in all posts in a particular categories. If a post belongs to 2 different categories, the result will show the same post twice. DISTINCT will remove the duplicate. If David wanted to see the category name in the result, then DISTINCT shouldn't be in the select statement.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but it won't work because of the SELECT *. If a post_id belongs to two different categories, you will select tuples like (1, 'Politic') and (1, 'Entertainment'). (Well, obviously, not with the WHERE clause, but you get the point.) There shouldn't be any duplicate, really, unless there are somehow two identical lines in the linker table.

Comment: The way the select statement is written with distinct p.*, the record is distinct even if it belongs to two categories. If he only cares about posts in a particular category, each post in the result should appear once. He knows the category so he doesn't need to include it in the result. My impression to his followup question 'what if 2 categories are assigned to One post?' is that he doesn't want to have duplicate post records in the result.

Comment: Vincent you're right! I didn't check my work. My intention was to have no duplicate in the result. Distinct wasn't necessary rather the where clause needs to be changed.

Comment: Vincent you're right! I didn't check my work. My intention was to have no duplicate in the result. Distinct wasn't necessary rather the where clause needs to be changed to "where c.id = (select cc.id from categories cc where cc.name = 'entertainment')"

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifying only one category in the WHERE clause, then the result will be a single row for each post ID.

Either way you can use DISTINCT or GROUP BY when the result could be more than one row per ID, but in that case i prefer the second one (GROUP BY).